# My application won't show up in Windows 10 Start search

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-10

I wrote a Win-32 desktop application in 1999 and have maintained it through the various iterations of Windows ever since. It didn't need a 64-bit address space so I never bothered to migrate it to the 64-bit apis.

Until Win 10 came along, I could type < the first few letters of my app's name> and the app would run.

In Win 10, I have to double click on the app to get it to run. If I try  the app's folder and its contents show in the start menu but not the app itself. I look under all apps and the app isn't there. I've added a shortcut to the start menu but even that hint isn't enough for Windows to find the app.  I tried creating a bat file that would fire off the app and placed the bat file in Programs Folder but that failed.

I never wrote an installer for the app. The app lives in its own folder which I  create by dragging it from a CD or network drive as I have migrated between all the Windows iterations since Win-98.

Is there now some xml file I must create that says "This is an app. Please Microsoft, include it in the start menu?" I had thought *.exe would suffice but apparently not. Perhaps *.exe code must now reside in Programs Folder, no exceptions allowed?

If it makes any difference, the application is written in C and compiled in Visual Developer 2008. It reads kid's handwritten responses to arithmetic questions.

More info I've dug up...

I noticed that Python shows up in Windows search but PHP doesn't. IIRC, I installed python with an installer whereas php was unzipped into its current location.

That establishes that a program need not reside in C:\Program Folder to show up in Start-search.

Then I discover that Python has a shortcut in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs but PHP doesn't. "That's it!" I think. Nope. Start-search now shows the folder I placed there but not the shortcut to the program. So residence in the start menu folder doesn't do it.

I am obnoxed.

..even more info...
I recompiled the entire project and now search finds the executable which suggests start-search is broken. Moreover, start-search only displays the app  if I completely type its name. In Win 7, just the first few letters suffice as is the case with most executables in win10.

The app still doesn't appear in the all apps section but then again, neither do the autodesk apps I have installed. OTOH, the autodesk apps appear by typing just a few letters.

At this point, it appears win10 start-search is broken.

Comment: I'm unclear on whether you are actually putting a shortcut to your program in the Start Menu folder or just a shortcut to its folder?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've tried both.

Answer (score 3):

Most .exe files don't appears in Windows Search under Win10 unless they are installed in program files folder... I try to find a way to circumvent this limitation cause lot of my files are portable applications on another drive.

In meantime here's a Workaround:  Make a folder `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\DummyApps"` and copy the shortcut of the app you want to be listed in "Search Results" in the DummyApps folder.

I've made a shorcut of "DummyApps" on my desktop to drop shortcut of programs I want to access by the search.

Regards

Comment: I'm having no luck with this approach. I added multiple shortcuts in that DummyApps folder but nothing ever shows up in the search :( Adding files there makes them show up in the "pinned to start menu" portion of the search bar, but typing in the name yields no results.

Comment: @Shenjoku Do you see at least the DummyFolder in the start menu ?

Comment: Nah, it doesn't show up. I ended up just giving up on this solution and installed Everything. I'm just going to use that as an alternative search engine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> I've added a shortcut to the start menu but even that hint isn't enough for Windows to find the app

do you mean that you added a shortcut here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs ?

If so, did you restart your pc (or at least explorer.exe)?

Adding a shortcut to the location above and restarting explorer.exe worked for me and it even added the app to the recently added apps section. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- step 1:win10 +x, open cmd  adminstration mode
- step 2:input 'start powershell' in cmd
- step 3:input 'Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}' in powershell